# Problem with location.back routing in angular with cordova

Tags: angular, cordova

I'm using angular7 prerendered with cordova 9.

All the navigation works fine, but when I try to use `location.back()` with the router, the url goes outside www and sometimes even crashes the app by going to an `invalid url`.

The same thing happens sometimes when using the device back button.

Any idea on which can be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution in an issue on their github. It looks like cordova overwrites the EventTarget causing the problem.

Placing the following code just before cordova.js solved it:

```
  <script>
      window.addEventListener = function () {
        (window.EventTarget || Window).prototype.addEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
      };
      window.removeEventListener = function () {
        (window.EventTarget || Window).prototype.removeEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
      };
      document.addEventListener = function () {
        (window.EventTarget || Document).prototype.addEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
      };
      document.removeEventListener = function () {
        (window.EventTarget || Document).prototype.removeEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
      };
  </script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can confirm this works for iOS and Android. Angular version: 11.2.4, Cordova version 10.0.0, iOS (platform) version 6.2.0, Android (platform) version 9.

Comment: Worked for me on Angular 9 w/ iOS where this issue had popped up.

Comment: This was the fix for me. My iOS build also failed after the last update. Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

[Try there, hoping it will be useful](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14645)