# Back button in the app cordova + angular is accumulating views in router-outlet

Tags: angular, cordova

if I have 4 routes in a menu and I navigate through them when I click the android's back button the views start to accumulate inside the router-outlet, this only happens when I run on my cell phone, on my computer it works normally.
When I press each button in the app work normally. The problem only happens when I start to come back with the android back button.

The same problem happens when I run with "cordova run browser".

One more important issue when using the back button on mobile or cordova browser the "router.url" in angular is not updated.

Thanks
[image: Start App]

[image: Image 2 is when I've browsed the buttons and used the android back button.]

```js
// app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ContainerComponent } from './_SYSTEM/container/container.component';
import { PresentationComponent } from './_APPLICATION/presentation/presentation.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './_APPLICATION/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './_SYSTEM/not-found/not-found.component';
import { FinancesComponent } from './_APPLICATION/finances/finances.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './_APPLICATION/services/services.component';
import { StockComponent } from './_APPLICATION/stock/stock.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: PresentationComponent},
  {path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'Finances', component: FinancesComponent},
  {path: 'Services', component: ServicesComponent},
  {path: 'Stock', component: StockComponent},
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```html
<!-- menu.component.html -->
{{router.url}}
<br>
<nav>
  <button routerLink="Dashboard" routerLinkActive="selected">Dashboard</button>
  <button routerLink="Finances" routerLinkActive="selected">Finances</button>
  <button routerLink="Services" routerLinkActive="selected">Services</button>
  <button routerLink="Stock" routerLinkActive="selected">Stock</button>
  <hr>
</nav>
```

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<app-head></app-head>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I made a new project very simple to test, the important parts of the project code referring to routes are posted above. For the rest, just create the components mentioned in the code.

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: @Gieted . Thanks for reviewing. I put the code above. Thanks.
I added two discoveries to the original text:
1)The same problem happens when I run with "cordova run browser".
2) One more important issue when I use the back button on the mobile or cordova browser the "router.url" in angular is not updated

Comment: I found this, solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901602/problem-with-location-back-routing-in-angular-with-cordova Thanks