# Backbutton causes screen overlapping on cordova app

Tags: android, angular, typescript, cordova

I'm working on an application made in angular that was exported to android using cordova. When pressing the back button the current screen is superimposed with elements from the previous screen. What could be causing this problem?

*I ran the browser version just to show the problem. Note that 3 different pages are "stacked" in the view after hitting the backbutton:
[screen overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb1iE.png).

I use lazy loading for screen navigation.
This is my navigation:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'contato',
        loadChildren: () => import('../contato/contato.module').then(m => m.ContatoModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'perfil',
        loadChildren: () => import('../perfil/perfil.module').then(m => m.PerfilModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'minhaAgenda',
        loadChildren: () => import('../minha-agenda/minha-agenda.module').then(m => m.MinhaAgendaModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'sobre',
        loadChildren: () => import('../sobre/sobre.module').then(m => m.SobreModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'agendar',
        loadChildren: () => import('../agendar/agendar.module').then(m => m.AgendarModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'alterarSenha',
        loadChildren: () => import('../alterar-senha/alterar-senha.module').then(m => m.AlterarSenhaModule)
      }
      ,
      {
        path: 'buscarBarbearia',
        loadChildren: () => import('../buscar-barbearia/buscar-barbearia.module').then(m => m.BuscarBarbeariaModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'detalheInformativo',
        loadChildren: () => import('../detalhe-informativo/detalhe-informativo.module').then(m => m.DetalheInformativoModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'menuAdministrativo',
        loadChildren: () => import('../menu-administrativo/menu-administrativo.module').then(m => m.MenuAdministrativoModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'cadastrarBarbearia',
        loadChildren: () => import('../cadastrar-barbearia/cadastrar-barbearia.module').then(m => m.CadastrarBarbeariaModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'barbearia',
        loadChildren: () => import('../barbearia/barbearia.module').then(m => m.BarbeariaModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'cadastrarBarbeiros',
        loadChildren: () => import('../cadastrar-barbeiros/cadastrar-barbeiros.module').then(m => m.CadastrarBarbeirosModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'barbeiro',
        loadChildren: () => import('../barbeiro/barbeiro.module').then(m => m.BarbeiroModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'agenda',
        loadChildren: () => import('../agenda/agenda.module').then(m => m.AgendaModule),
        canActivate: [FuncionarioGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'cadastrarServicos',
        loadChildren: () => import('../cadastrar-servicos/cadastrar-servicos.module').then(m => m.CadastrarServicosModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'servico',
        loadChildren: () => import('../servico/servico.module').then(m => m.ServicoModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'relatorios',
        loadChildren: () => import('../relatorios/relatorios.module').then(m => m.RelatoriosModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'cadastrarHorarios',
        loadChildren: () => import('../cadastrar-horarios/cadastrar-horarios.module').then(m => m.CadastrarHorariosModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'horarios',
        loadChildren: () => import('../horarios/horarios.module').then(m => m.HorariosModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'filiarBarbearia',
        loadChildren: () => import('../filiar-barbearia/filiar-barbearia.module').then(m => m.FiliarBarbeariaModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'clientesFiliados',
        loadChildren: () => import('../clientes-filiados/clientes-filiados.module').then(m => m.ClientesFiliadosModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'noticias',
        loadChildren: () => import('../noticias/noticias.module').then(m => m.NoticiasModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'cadastrarInformativos',
        loadChildren: () => import('../cadastrar-informativos/cadastrar-informativos.module').then(m => m.CadastrarInformativosModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'informativos',
        loadChildren: () => import('../informativos/informativos.module').then(m => m.InformativosModule),
        canActivate: [AdministradorGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'cadastrarPesquisa',
        loadChildren: () => import('../cadastrar-pesquisa/cadastrar-pesquisa.module').then(m => m.CadastrarPesquisaModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'pesquisa',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pesquisa/pesquisa.module').then(m => m.PesquisaModule)
      },
      // {
      //   path: 'cadastrarNotificacoes',
      //   loadChildren: () => import('../cadastrar-notificacoes/cadastrar-notificacoes.module').then(m => m.CadastrarNotificacoesModule)
      // },
      {
        path: 'notificacoes',
        loadChildren: () => import('../notificacoes/notificacoes.module').then(m => m.NotificacoesModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'faturas',
        loadChildren: () => import('../faturas/faturas.module').then(m => m.FaturasModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'detalheNotificacao',
        loadChildren: () => import('../detalhe-notificacao/detalhe-notificacao.module').then(m => m.DetalheNotificacaoModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'cadastrarComissao',
        loadChildren: () => import('../cadastrar-comissao/cadastrar-comissao.module').then(m => m.CadastrarComissaoModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'comissao',
        loadChildren: () => import('../comissao/comissao.module').then(m => m.ComissaoModule)
      },
    ],
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
  },

  {
    path: 'login', component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'cadastro', component: CadastroComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'esqueceuSenha', component: EsqueceuSenhaComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'alterarSenhaDeslog', component: AlterarSenhaDeslogComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'codigoRecuperacao', component: CodigoRecuperacaoComponent
  },
  { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }

];
```

I tried modifying cordova.js but got no results

Comment: What do you mean with "backbutton", the devices/browsers native back function or the ionic nav element? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button

Comment: I managed to solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55901733/17775848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but in a quick search I came up with below solution:

Clear the navigation stack whenever a screen is loaded. You can do this by setting the clearHistory option to true when navigating to a new screen:

```
this.router.navigate(['/path/to/screen'], { clearHistory: true });
```